# Function says it's "not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am getting an error saying that "prepnewissue" is not defined when I try to upload my code to a website html. Basically this function is supposed to make it to where when you click the sidebar menu you get a little cursos (red dot) that is able to be placed on the map, it's not activating however. When I hover over the sidebar it just says "javascript:prepNewIssue('Repairable')" and the same for the other one too.

---

```
function prepNewIssue(kind)
  {
     panner.disable();
     $("div[id^='m']").hide();
     $('#plan-wrapper').css('cursor', 'crosshair');
     $('#plan').bind('mousedown', {kind: kind}, newIssue);
  }
```

```
  <p>
  <ul class="sf-menu sf-vertical">
     <li><a href="#">New ID</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="javascript:prepNewIssue('Repairable')">Repairable</a></li>
           <li><a href="javascript:prepNewIssue('Survey Mark')">Survey Mark</a></li>
        </ul>
     <li>
  </ul>
  </p>
```

Comment: You're using jQuery, for Gods sake use proper event handlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline event handlers require that the specified functions are global.

Chances are your function is defined inside a `$(document).ready` block, and hence it's only defined in that block's scope and not global.

As you're using jQuery, you should use that to register your event handlers and scrap the inline registrations.

Comment: I really appreciate the answer, I double checked to see if it was indeed global and everything seemed to check out. I am confused what you meant by inline registrations though

Comment: @JustinGonzalez I mean the `href="javascript:..."`, i.e. DOM0 links.  You should use jQuery's `.on` method to add JS handlers to elements.  And as FelixKling points out on the other answer, you should normally use a `div`, `span` or `button` for actions like this instead of an `<a>`.

Answer (score 0):

The href attribute is for the url that you want to navigate to when the link is clicked. If you want to run a script when the link is clicked, you need to specify that in an onclick event for the HTML element.

If you don't actually want the browser to navigate to a new page, you shouldn't be using a link element ().

Comment: Prefixing it with `javascript:` specifies that it is a function call, not an HTTP request

Comment: @Dennis: Yes, but answer still holds some truth. A link has a specific *semantic*, i.e. it links to another document. Unfortunately links are misused as buttons far too often.